# Can't Move Group backwards! Corona SDK

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm new here, I'm trying to do a videogame for android with corona SDK, but I'm stuck with the creation of random particle on the background,
here is the code:

```
local menu = composer.newScene()

function menu:create( event )
  local bg = self.view
  local particlesGroup = self.view
  local sceneGroup = self.view


  blackLayer = display.newImageRect(  "black_layer.png",  1280, 300 )
  blackLayer.y = display.contentCenterY + 150
  blackLayer.x = display.contentCenterX
  blackLayer.alpha = 0.6



  background = display.newImageRect( "background.png",  1280 , 720 )
  background.x = display.contentCenterX
  background.y = display.contentCenterY




  playBtn = widget.newButton( {
    id="playBtn",
    x=display.contentCenterX+350,
    y=blackLayer.y,
    labelColor = { default={0.922, 0.938, 0.941}, over={0.9, 0.3, 0.234, 0.6}},
    label = "Play Now",
    defaultFile = "redBtn.png",
    overFile = "whiteBtn.png",
    width = 200,
    height = 200,
    fontSize = 30,
    font = "Fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf",
    --onRelease = composer.gotoScene( "game")
  } )


  settingsBtn = widget.newButton( {
      id="playBtn",
      x=display.contentCenterX,
      y=blackLayer.y-50,
      font = "Fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf",
      label = "Settings",
      defaultFile = "rectWhiteBtn.png",
      overFile = "rectRedBtn.png",
      width =250,
      height = 100,
      fontSize = 30,
      labelColor = { default={0.9, 0.3, 0.234} , over={0.922, 0.938, 0.941, 0.6} },
      onRelease = gotoSettings
    } )


  highScoresBtn = widget.newButton( {
        id="highScoresBtn",
        x=display.contentCenterX,
        y=settingsBtn.y + 100,
        font = "Fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf",
        label = "High Scores",
        defaultFile = "rectWhiteBtn.png",
        overFile = "rectRedBtn.png",
        width =250,
        height = 100,
        fontSize = 30,
        labelColor = { default={0.9, 0.3, 0.234} , over={0.922, 0.938, 0.941, 0.6} },
        --onRelease = composer.gotoScene("highScores")
      } )

      bg:insert(background)
      sceneGroup:insert(blackLayer)
      sceneGroup:insert(playBtn)
      sceneGroup:insert(settingsBtn)
      sceneGroup:insert(highScoresBtn)

      function generateParticles()
        local xy=math.random(30,70)
        local newParticle = display.newImageRect( particlesGroup,  objectSheet , math.random(13), xy, xy )
        newParticle.x = (math.random(1280)*math.random(88932))%1280
        newParticle.y = (math.random(720)*math.random(13546))%720
        newParticle.alpha = 0
        transition.to( newParticle, {alpha=1, time=150, onComplete=dimParticle, onCompleteParams=newParticle})
      end

      function generateParticlesSmall()
        local xy=math.random(5,15)
        local newParticle = display.newImageRect( particlesGroup,  objectSheet , 1, xy, xy )
        newParticle.x = (math.random(1280)*math.random(88932))%1280
        newParticle.y = (math.random(720)*math.random(13546))%720
        newParticle.alpha = 0
        transition.to( newParticle, {alpha=1, time=150, onComplete=dimParticle, onCompleteParams=newParticle})
      end

end


function menu:show( event )
  local bg = self.view
  local particlesGroup = self.view
  local sceneGroup = self.view
  local phase = event.phase



    if ( phase == "will" ) then


      bigPTimer1=timer.performWithDelay( 1, generateParticles, 0 )
      -- Start the timer which calls 'generateParticles' for each ms


      smallPTimer=timer.performWithDelay( 1, generateParticlesSmall, 0 )
      -- Start the timer which calls 'generateParticlesSmall' for each ms
      particlesGroup:toBack()

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then


        if event.phase=="began"then
        end
        if event.phase=="ended"then
        end


    end
end


function menu:hide( event )
  local bg = self.view
  local particlesGroup = self.view
  local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)



    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen

    end
end

function menu:destroy( event )
  local bg = self.view
  local particlesGroup = self.view
  local sceneGroup = self.view
end

--Funzioni

local function gotoGame()
    composer.gotoScene( "game" )
end

local function gotoHighScores()
    composer.gotoScene( "highscores" )
end

function gotoSettings()
  reproduceEffet1()
  timer.cancel(bigPTimer1)
  timer.cancel(smallPTimer)
  composer.gotoScene( "settings", options)
end

--funzioni

local function removetotally( particle )
  display.remove( particle )
end

function dimParticle( particle )
    transition.to( particle, {alpha=0, time=500, onComplete = removetotally, onCompleteParams = particle})
end

--

menu:addEventListener( "create", menu )
menu:addEventListener( "show", menu )
menu:addEventListener( "hide", menu )
menu:addEventListener( "destroy", menu )


--

return menu
```

All functions are working perfectly, but the problem is that I can't move back the group of particles, between bg and sceneGroup.

Thank for listening me.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have only 1 display group.

```
local bg = self.view
local particlesGroup = self.view
local sceneGroup = self.view
```

You need to create `particlesGroup` as child in order to move it back:

Declare local variables on the top of the file:

```
local menu = composer.newScene()
local bg, particlesGroup
```

Create groups in `menu:create`

```
bg = display.newGroup()
particlesGroup = display.newGroup()
local sceneGroup = self.view
sceneGroup:insert(bg)
sceneGroup:insert(particlesGroup) -- here particlesGroup will be on the top

particlesGroup:toBack() --now particlesGroup is under bg
```